# Omnigraffle not opening xcodeproj file

Tags: ios, xcode, uml

I am trying to generate a uml diagram of a current project I just inherited. I have seen several places that referenced omnigraffle as the best tool for this as it has been said that I can just drag my .xcodeproject file onto the icon. However,  I get the following popup message:

"The document “tangott.xcodeproj” could not be opened. This framework or project does not contain any Objective-C interfaces. OmniGraffle only diagrams class hierarchies in Objective-C."

Is this still possible? I have OS 10.7.3 and the latest version of Omnigraffle. If not, is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Are you sure it contains Objective-C? Any classes that have the extension .mm instead of .m and/or contain c++ code will not be parsed by OmniGraffle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I opened these files with Xcode and realized that I would have to open the project file from the same directory as the classes. I had copied it over somewhere else and dragged it from there over the icon but it did not carry the reference location of my class files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check "File->Open->Select your Xcode **folder**" instead " File->Open->Select your XcodeProject file". It means: dragging its (.xcodeproj) **containing folder** onto the OmniGraffle application icon

Best luck for you,